# Git checkout <commit> and then commit and retain all commits

Tags: git, version-control

I have a problem to solve on Git , here are the sequence of steps we i perform

Let say i make 3 commits on master

```
- commit-1
- commit-2
- commit-3
```

Now i checkout to commit-2

```
git checkout commit-2
```

then i make commit-4

Now i want to retain all four commits on the master branch and my master branch's ***git log*** should  look  in the following  order

```
Commit-3
commit-4
commit-2
commit-1
```

How do i achieve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you checkout `commit-2`, you are in a [**detached HEAD mode**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309).

The first things to do is to create a branch where your `commit-4` is:

```
git checkout commit-2
git add ...
git commit -m "commit-4"
git checkout -b tmp

1--2--3 (master) 
    \
     4 (tmp)
```

Then you can rebase `master` on top of it in order to replay `commit-3` on top of `commit-4`

```
git rebase tmp master

1--2--4--3 (master, tmp)
```

Comment: But this has put commit 4 over commit 3 . But i want all the commits on the new branch(tmp) on top of the checked out commit (commit-2), but below the commits above the initally checked out commit(commit-3) , that is , i want commit-3 on top of commit-4

Comment: @KarthicRao no it doesn't put 4 over 3: it put 3 (master) on top of tmp (4)

Comment: Thank you , I had checked out tmp first and then made commit 4 . This works :)

Answer (score 1):

I would do it as follows

first you commit commits 1, 2, 3

```
git commit -am "commit 1"
git commit -am "commit 2"
git commit -am "commit 3"
```

then you go back to commit 2

```
git checkout <<hash or HEAD^>
```

then you commit commit 4

```
git commit -am "commit 4"
```

then you merge your detached head into new head

```
git merge <<reference of commit 3>>
```

please comment out if there is a better way of doing it

Comment: merge would create merge conflict and i could commit only one of the version . what if lets say im just working on one file and i want all snapshots of the change without having to solve merge conflicts